# Transfer function analisis

Tags: homework-and-exercises, linear-systems

[image: poles and zeros of the function]
I've seen this problem solved out there but I don't quite understand what it is done

Based on the transfer function 
$$ P(s)=\frac{(s+2)}{(s+0.5)(s+4)} $$
it is asked  to graphically evaluate the unit step response.
I understand the poles and zeros are like in the picture. The step pole is in the origin of the plane, then its a zero on -2, and poles in -.5 and -4.

Then it is said to do this ( I don't understand )
$$R_{1}=\frac{2}{0.5(4)}=1; arg R_{1}=0$$
$$R_{2}=\frac{1.5}{0.5(3.5)}=0.857; arg R_{2}=-180$$
$$R_{3}=\frac{2}{4(3.5)}=0.143; arg R_{1}=-180$$

next is :
$$ y(t)=R_{1}+R_{2}e^{(-0.5t)}+R_{3}e^{(-4t)}=1-0.857e^{(-0.5t)}-0.143e^{(-4t)}$$

But how are calculated the values of $R_{1}$, what does mean that, and how the angle its calculated?

---

**Update:** The one I've done before is like this

$$ P(s)=\frac{1}{(s+1)(s+2)} $$
The magnitude and angle of $P(jω)$ for $ω=1$
  is 
[image: problem solved]
$$ P(j1)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}\sqrt{5}}=0.316 $$
add the angle 
$$argP(j1)=-26.6-45=-71.6$$

But I don't see how this fit in the question before.

Comment: Hint: this is a direct application of the [partial fraction decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition).

Comment: this should be migrated to either the [electronics.se] or the [dsp.se].

Comment: I ve done this but based on transfer functions to get the magnitud and angle of the tf, but alwas  is a reference over the $jω$ axis not over the $σ$ , I mean the gain, so how this must be interpreted, and why are the values of the denominator set this way?

Comment: If you have done it, then please add to your question the decomposition of $P(s)$ that you have obtained and we can discuss it further. Don't forget to add @user in your comment  if you want user to be informed about your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem as though you're under the misconception that $s$ is always an imaginary variable. This is not so; from a sophisticated viewpoint, most of the theoretical results about Laplace transforms come from treating $s$ as a complex variable and from treating the trnsfer function as a meromorphic function of that complex variable. A more accessible way to understand this viewpoint is to consider the meaning of the transfer function $H(s)$ when the input is a damped sinusoid, rather than a sinusoid, *i.e.* of the form $\exp((\sigma+ i\,\omega)\,t)$. The particular integral for the output of the system is still the same damped sinusoid $H(\sigma + i\,\omega)\,\exp((\sigma+ i\,\omega)\,t)$, *i.e* the original scaled by $H(\sigma + i\,\omega)$. You can show this by inverting the Laplace transform of the output, *i.e* $\frac{H(s)}{s-\sigma-i\,\omega}$, using tables. So the simple results for sinusoidal inputs generalize straightforwardly to damped sinusoids.

That being said, what one is trying to do is express the rational function $H(s)$ as a partial fraction series of the form:

$$H(s) = \sum\limits_j \left( \frac{a_{j1}}{s - s_j} + \frac{a_{j2}}{(s - s_j)^2} + \cdots + \frac{a_{j k_j}}{(s - s_j)^{k_j}} \right)\tag{1}$$

where the $s_j$ are the complex zeros of the denominator of $H(s)$ (*i.e.* the poles of $H(s)$) and the $k_j$ are the multiplicities of the poles. Such an expansion always exists; there is a straightforward formula for the co-efficients $a_{jk}$ and the *inverse Laplace transforms for all the summed terms in the expression are known*. See the ["Residue Method"section of the "Partial Fraction Decomposition"Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition#Residue_method).

You're calculating the step response, so you're trying to find the inverse Laplace transform of

$$\frac{(s+2)}{s\,(s+0.5)(s+4)}=\frac{R_1}{s}+\frac{R_2}{s+\frac{1}{2}}+\frac{R_3}{s+4}\tag{2}$$

Here all the poles are of multiplicity 1, so the simple formula with constant numerators above holds; either use the residue method as described by the Wiki page, *e.g.*

$$R_2 = \lim\limits_{s\to-\frac{1}{2}}\frac{(s+2)}{s\,\left(s+\frac{1}{2}\right)(s+4)} \times \left(s+\frac{1}{2}\right) = \left.\frac{s+2}{s\,(s+4)}\right|_{s=-\frac{1}{2}}\tag{3}$$

or you can simply put all the terms on the RHS of (2) over the common denominator $s\,(s+0.5)(s+4)$ which will give you equations for the $R_j$. Once you have the $R_j$, then the RHS of (2) has inverse Laplace transform $R_1+R_2\,\exp(-t/2) + R_3\,\exp(-4\,t)$.

Comment: indeed it is a very concise expo about, but what about the angles , isn’t supposed to be the angle of the poles relative to zeros. i.e. the -2 relative to zero, -0.5 and -4(0,0 and -180 degrees respectively ? Thanks for taking your time.

Comment: @riccs_0x The angles come naturally from the above methods: they are the phases of the complex numbers in (3). In this case they are all real, so (3) will give you the appropriate sign. When the poles are complex, the arise in complex conjugate pairs $s_0,\,s_0^ast$ (for real co-efficient transfer functions) and the pair residues are also complex conjugates, so you get terms of the form $R\,\exp(-s_0\,t) + R^* \exp(-s_0^*\,t)$, which is a real valued function of $t$. The relevant phase is that of the damped sinusoid $R\,\exp(-s_0\,t) + R^* \exp(-s_0^*\,t)$.